# powershell scriptblock expanding for debug

Tags: powershell

How can I expand all variables in a `$scriptblock` without manually writing out all variables:

I like to do it like this:

```
>>$scriptBlock = {Install-Package -Name $($Using:h.Name) \
>>  -RequiredVersion $($Using:h.Version) \
>>  -Source $Using:nuget_source -Force -SkipDependencies}
>>write-host ("install-command: {0}" -f $scriptBlock)

install-command: Install-Package -Name $($Using:h.Name) \
  -RequiredVersion $($Using:h.Version) -Source $Using:nuget_source \
  -Force -SkipDependencies
```

But I have to do it like this, which will make it hard to automate:

```
>>write-host ("install-command: Install-Package -Name {0} -RequiredVersion {1} -Source {2} -Force -SkipDependencies" \
>>  -f $h.Name, $h.Version, $nuget_source)

install-command: Install-Package -Name Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver \
  -RequiredVersion 3.150.1 -Source https://nuget.org/api/v2/ -Force -SkipDependencies
```

The answer in [powershell expand variable in scriptblock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551893/powershell-expand-variable-in-scriptblock) does not help because it is already a scriptblock:

```
>> [Scriptblock]$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create($testScriptBlock)
>> $sb
Install-Package -Name $($Using:h.Name) -RequiredVersion \ 
   $($Using:h.Version) -Source $Using:nuget_source -Force -SkipDependencies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$Using:` is only available in sessions ([About Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-6)). Maybe you can convert the scriptblock to string and replace `$Using:` with `$` [and expand it](https://www.appliedis.com/expanding-variable-strings-in-powershell/).

```
write-host ("install-command: {0}" -f $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($scriptBlock.ToString().Replace('$Using:', '$')) )
```