# Create scriptblocks with expanded variables

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I know that this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063570/how-to-resolve-variables-in-a-powershell-script-block) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551893/powershell-expand-variable-in-scriptblock). But for one reason or another it doesn't really work for us.

**Desired result**

2 scriptblocks that are usable with the Pester parameter `ParameterFilter` whre only the variable `$testTable` is expanded:

```bsh
{
    ($Query -like "*SELECT * FROM tableOne* 
        WHERE TicketNr IS NOT NULL AND TicketCloseDate IS NULL*")
}
{
    ($Query -like "*SELECT * FROM tableWto* 
        WHERE TicketNr IS NOT NULL AND TicketCloseDate IS NULL*")
}
```

The code below does not work because we need to escape everything within the `$testQuery`. Isn't there a way to only expand the `$testTable` and not the other pieces?

```bsh
foreach ($testTable in @('tableOne', 'tableTwo')) {
    $testQuery = "*SELECT * FROM $testTable* 
    WHERE TicketNr IS NOT NULL AND TicketCloseDate IS NULL*"
    
    [ScriptBlock]::create("`$Query `-like $testQuery")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```bsh
foreach ($testTable in @('tableOne', 'tableTwo')) {   
    [ScriptBlock]::create(@"
    (`$Query -like  "*SELECT * FROM $testTable*
    WHERE TicketNr IS NOT NULL AND TicketCloseDate IS NULL*" )
"@)
}
```